# Return value did not show up in html

Tags: javascript, html

This is HTML codes:

```
<html>

<head>
<script src = "tempScript.js" text = "text/javascript"> 
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <h3><b>Farenheit to Celsius Converter</b></h3>
    <p>Enter a temperature in degrees F:&nbsp;
        <input type="text" id="textbox" /></p>
    <p>Click this button to calculate the temperature in degrees C:&nbsp;
        <input type="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="temp ()" /></p>
    <p>Temperature in degrees C is:&nbsp;<input type="temp ()"/></p>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is javascript code:

```
function temp ()

{
    var f = document.getElementById("textbox").value;

    var c = ((f - 32.0)*5.0) / 9.0;

    return c;
}
```

Were there any problem with this codes?

Actually, what I wanted to do was to get the return value and then display the value in the field of "Temperature in degrees C is". But I could not find the mistakes.Please point it out if I have mistakes.

Comment: The problem is solved and thanks to all of your answers:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<input type="temp ()"/>` is not valid html. try this.

```
<html>

<head>
<script src = "tempScript.js" text = "text/javascript"> 
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <h3><b>Farenheit to Celsius Converter</b></h3>
    <p>Enter a temperature in degrees F:&nbsp;
        <input type="text" id="textbox" /></p>
    <p>Click this button to calculate the temperature in degrees C:&nbsp;
        <input type="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="temp ()" /></p>
    <p>Temperature in degrees C is:&nbsp;<input id="tmpDisplay" value=""/></p>
</body>

</html>
<script>
    function temp ()

{
    var f = document.getElementById("textbox").value;

    var c = ((f - 32.0)*5.0) / 9.0;
    document.getElementById("tmpDisplay").value=c;
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Note: I added and `id` for the `input` where the result is to be displayed. You set the value of that input to the calculated value in your javascript. Note the `return false` in the script. This is to prevent the form from being submitted to the server.

Comment: Wow,yours can work:)Appreciate your help very much but what is the meaning of "return false"?And when we should use this?

Comment: if you don't return false from the submit click the form gets actually submitted.

Answer (score 1):

You cant call/assign method in 'value' below is the correct method

```
    <h3><b>Farenheit to Celsius Converter</b></h3>
<p>Enter a temperature in degrees F:&nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="textbox" /></p>
<p>Click this button to calculate the temperature in degrees C:&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="temp();" /></p>
<p>Temperature in degrees C is:&nbsp;<input id="degrees" /></p>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function temp() {
        var f = document.getElementById("textbox").value;

        var c = ((f - 32.0) * 5.0) / 9.0;

        document.getElementById("degrees").value = c;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: onclick="temp();" this can be changed to onclick="temp(); return false;" if you dont want todo a postback

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting it in `type()` of input, put it as value. Working fiddle-

http://jsfiddle.net/RDue8/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in line:

```
<input type="temp ()"/>
```

The type of the input the format it's shown in. You need to add a value to return to:

```
<input type="text" value="temp()"/>
```

This should then display the result in html.

Comment: `<input type="text" value="temp()"/>` wont do anything just put `temp()` text in the input.